# Android Dynamic ListView filtering Row Value Issue

Tags: android

I have a dynamic list view that is getting data from server after each 3 seconds and adding new data when ever get new data to the list. Actually i want to set data to list according to list row item text value.Suppose if any row has the text value  chat request then it should appear on the top of the list always.

How can i do this?can anyone help me?

Is there any method in android by using that i can filter the text according to that i will able to add that row to the top of the list view.

Actually i am getting data from server and adding to the listview.each after 3 seconds i am getting new data and this data i am adding to list.if this response contain the text chat request then i want after parsing the response the chat request text should be added in the list firstly.

How to filter listview data and add specific text on the top of the row in android listview.Can anyone help me?

I have a custom adapter and whenever i got response i am spiting it  and storing data for the list in multiple arraylist because my list row has data like ipaddress,statustext,durationtext and no. of visit text value and one button invite.If any chat request come then invite button will be hide and Accept and deny button will appears and on clicking on accept a chat window open and accept button text change to join and deny button will be invisible.

I have to show chat request message remain at the top of the row until the user does not something.

Comment: You should add more details: Do you have a custom adapter, where do you store the data for the list(An ArrayList of strings, other custom objects, another data structure etc) do you put only Strings in the list, do you want the `chat request` message to remain at the top until the user does something etc

Comment: Yes,i have a custom adapter and i am storing data for the list in multiple arraylist becauese my list row has contain like ipaddress,statustext,durationtext and no. of visit text value.I have to chat request message remain at the top until the user does not something.

Comment: Without any code to look at I can only recommend that when you get the `chat request` message to make sure to put it at the top of your `ArrayList` that goes in the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the date in a List you cann filter the new values and if the value chat you add it to the list with the index eg. list.add("text",0); and than you should  rebuild the ListView with the list.

Comment: My question was different and you answer it differently.Actually i am getting data from server and adding to the listview.each after 3 seconds i am getting new data and this data i am adding to list.if this response contain the text chat request then i want after parsing the response the chat request text should be added in the list firstly.